# php script that deletes itself after completion

Tags: php, file-io

There's a problem that I'm currently investigating: after a coworker left, one night some files that he created, basicly all his work on a completed project that the boss hasn't payed him for, got deleted. From what I know all access credentials have been changed.

Is it possible to do this by setting up a file to do the deletion task and then delete the file in question? Or something similar that would change the code after the task has been done? Is this untraceable? (i'm thinking he could have cleverly disguised the request as a normal request, and i have skimmed through the code base and through the raw access logs and found nothing).

Comment: That's why you use source-control systems.

Comment: On top of version control, I'd also recommend paying your developers to your boss. :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's impossible to tell whether this is what actually happened or not, but setting up a mechanism that deletes  files is trivial.

This works for me:

```
<? // index.php
   unlink("index.php");
```

it would be a piece of cake to set up a script that, if given a certain GET variable for example, would delete itself and a number of other files.

Except for the server access logs, I'm not aware of a way to trace this - however, depending on your OS and file system, an undelete utility may be able to recover the files.

It has already been said in the comments how to prevent this - using centralized source control, and backups. (And of course paying your developers - although this kind of stuff can happen to anyone.)

Answer (score 3):

> Is is possible to do this by setting up a file to do the deletion task
>   and then delete the file in question?

Yes it is. He could have left an innoculous looking php file on the server which when accessed over the web later, would give him shell access. Getting this file to self delete when he is done is possible.

Create a php file with the following in it:

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['vanish'] == 'y') {
        echo "You wouldn't find me the next time you look!";
        @unlink(preg_replace('!\(\d+\)\s.*!', '', __FILE__));
    } else {
        echo "I can self destruct ... generally";
    }
?>
```

Put on your server and navigate to it. Then navigate again with a "vanish=y" argument and see what happens